# Why does a 3d line of segments with constant angles always make a helix?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have a chain of discrete segments, of equal sizes, built by the following rules:

1)every next segment rotates around it's Y axis by 7 degrees,

2)then it pivots at the join with the previous segment by 4 degrees.

Regardless of the angles used, the resulting pattern is always a kind of helix, it spirals forwards into space indefinitely.

In 2d, such a ruleset would always form a spirograph rotating around a point.

Why does the rule set make helix shapes and never 3d spirographs?

[image]

Comment: Is that $Y$ global or segment-local? I don't understand what is going on in 2).

Comment: The segments are sequenced like spinning tops with 4 sides arranged in a stack, every segment is rotated by n degrees and inclined towards side 1 by n degrees.

Comment: Another interpretation: rule 2 makes a segment of a 2d circle, rule 1 deviates the segment away from the 2d circle. if i run rule 1 only once rule 2 has made a circle, i will have torus shapes. these 2 rules tend to always make projective spirals. to make spirographs i have to find another rule, which i dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this explanation be a bit too imprecise, but I think it can be made to work. (In what follows, it may help to consider the image of a triangular helix joint shown [here](http://digitalpipefitter.com/docs/jointhelix.html).)

Take two consecutive segments of your helix, and consider the isosceles triangle with them as its legs. Draw the line in 3D which bisects the joint angle, and repeat this construction for the next joint. Note that the two triangles formed this way do not lie in the same plane due to the rotations; consequently the two bisectors will not intersect and are skew. Consequently they are both perpendicular to some common axis.

If we repeat this again, we receive another bisector; however, it stands in the same geometric relation to the second bisector as that did to the first bisector. Thus we will get a sequence of bisectors which are all displaced from each other by the same amount and lie along a common axis: this provides the skeleton of which our segmented curve is built. But that requires the curve so formed to be a segmented helix.

Answer (score 1):

I have been studying this extensively; I have an open-source repo with a draft technical paper that describes it in some detail: https://github.com/PubInv/segmented-helixes/blob/master/doc/StackingHelix.pdf

Additionally, I have created interactive 3D software (runs in browser) that somewhat demonstrates it: https://pubinv.github.io/segmented-helixes/index.html

@Semiclassical's answer is correct and anticipates a major calculational approach.  But let me offer a different answer.

AFAIK, Eric Lord was the first to put into writing what I call Lord's Observation:

> In nature, helical structures arise when identical structural subunits
>   combine sequentially, the orientational and translational relation
>   between each unit and its predecessor remaining constant.

This is exactly what you are doing; using a repeated rule. (By the way, it is possible that a repeated rule produces a "degenerate" helix with no travel along the axis, which looks like a torus---which is what you call a "3D Spirograph". However, you have to select values carefully for this to be true---you can do it with my software by varying the twist slider close to zero.)

A proof sketch of Lord's Observation is:

Every physical displacement is described by a screw (a rotation around an axis and a slide on the same axis) by Chasles' theorem.) If you use the same rule, the next application of the rule produces a rotation about the axis and by the same distance starting where you left off. By induction, the repeated rule is always about the same screw axis. Since rotation about an axis preserves the distance to that axis, the figure produced by repeated application has concurrent with it a helix whose axis is screw axis and radius is fixed. (End of Proof Sketch.)

[Image of prisms joined face-to-face forming helix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyEy1.png)